# Detect notification popup using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications

I am creating userscript for messenger site I use. Is it possible to detect when site create notification pop up(usually on right bottom of screen) and get content of notification?

```js
document.addEventListener('???', function(e) {  // when I get notification popup(get message)
    // and get content of notification
});
```

[image: notification popup exampole]

Comment: Do you have the source code of this site?

Comment: No - site is Discord and I amn't a developer of  site. Javascript from site is uglified(packed) with webpack so I can not edit original javascript from site

Comment: You can try to hook the 'constructor' of `window.Notification` and get the content when the notification instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

In websites I believe there's a **Notifications API** in which you can check here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

It has all functions to **request** permissions, **detect** & **listen** to notifications on in websites. For example:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let promise = Notification.requestPermission();
  // wait for permission
})
```